# Not concatenating in same line

Tags: python, python-2.7, concatenation

This is my code:

```
with open('test1.txt') as f:
    print "printing f"
    print f
    print '**********************'
    for line in f:
        print "printing line each"
        print line
        print '********'
        line2=line.upper()+"abc"
        print "printing line 2"
        print line2
        print '********'
        open('testout.txt','a').write(line2)
```

And for this I am getting this output:

```
printing line 2
ROMA
abc
```

instead of:

```
printing line 2
ROMAabc
```

I can't understand what is wrong, can someone help me understand?

P.S: I tried using `join` method as well, and still got the same result.

I am using python 2.7

Comment: It appears that `line` has a trailing `/n` or newline therefore your actual output is `ROMA/nabc`

Comment: The line in the file has a newline at the end of it. The call to `upper` does not kill the newline. You therefore want `line2 = line.strip().upper()`

Comment: show us the content of `test1.txt` file

Comment: You should make sure you reproduce your indentation properly when posting Python code. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

line contains '\n' at the end, you can use this for your goal:

```
line.strip().upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [.strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip), so

```
print line.strip().upper()
```

You're reading a new line separated document. It's got special "\n"s inside.